# How to configure Hibernate Application in OpenShift that uses PostgreSql Database

Tags: hibernate, openshift

Can anyone please help me in using Hibernate Application in RedHat's OpenShift cloud. Am using postgreSQL Database. In local machine am able to make transactions to & from database. But, when I tried to run in openshift cloud am getting error as '**Could not open connection**'.
Please provide me with an information in accessing postgreSQL by using Hibernate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

OpenShift provides you with environment variables that you can retrieve from your Java application:

```
OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST=127.x.x.x
OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PASSWORD=xxx
OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PORT=5432
OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL=postgresql://xxx:xxx@127.x.x.x:5432
OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_USERNAME=xxx
```

If you deploy your application in JBossAS 7 or Wildfly, you should just configure your persistence.xml to use the POSTGRESQL Datasource configured in the `standalone.xml` file (available in the `.openshift/config folder in your project) with the following JNDI name:`java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS`

In both cases, you don't need to put your database credentials in your code, your application will get them when running on OpenShift ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you set these 3 env vars at your OpenShift Console / Your Project / Applications / Deployment / Your Deployment (despesas in my case) / Environment:

[image: Deployment / Environment]